# Center image in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Canvas that's 300x300 and an image that 150x150.

How can I draw this image in the center of this Canvas. What do i write in context.translate and context.drawImage?

On what browsers will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For argument's sake, let's imagine your image is a rectangle.

```
ctx.fillRect(
             (canvasWidth - width) / 2, 
             (canvasHeight - height) / 2, 
             width, 
             height
            );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWsWN/).

The same form of calculations apply.

Comment: i am using context.drawImage. Can you tell me how it's done with context?

Comment: @RussT: Pretty much the same as `fillRect()`, just remember the additional leading argument for the image.

Comment: What if the image width is greater than the canvas width?

Comment: @alex ... ya... would that be doing width - canvasWidth instead (flipping it around)?

Answer (score 0):

the centre of the image should be placed at 150,150. the top left of the image, which is often the point used to draw things, should be places at `(150-150/2),(150-150/2)`  assuming that `0,0` is the top left corner. More generally top left should be at `((W-w)/2),((H-h)/2)` where W and H are the width and height of the canvas and w and h are the width and height of the image to be drawn.

(sorry if you were asking 'how do I draw an image on a canvas')

Comment: so that does mean i have to write context.translate((150-150/2),(150-150/2)). Can you give a full example of what context.translate and context.drawImage() contain?